# Matlab does not correctly calculate the limit of the function of complex variable

Tags: matlab

I am trying to calculate the limit as z goes to 0 of function f(z) = Re(z^2)/|z|^2

```
syms z complex
f = real(z^2)/abs(z)^2
limit(f,z,0)
```

Matlab's answer is 1, whereas the true answer is: this function has no limit as z -> 0.

Comment: `.../toolbox/symbolic/symbolic/@sym/limit.m` eventually tries to run a command like `mupadmex('symobj::map', 'real(z^2)/abs(z)^2', 'symobj::limit', 'z', '0', dir)` to solve the limit, where `dir` is one of 'Real', 'Left' or 'Right'. According to `doc(symengine,'limit')`, the MuPAD `limit()` function only supports real numbers. So maybe there is not much hope here...

Comment: From the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.limit.html): Matlab's `limit` computes the bidirectional limit along the _real_ axis. So the result `1` is correct

Answer (score 4):

Not a full solution of your problem, but you can get the real results with the following modifications of your code:

```
syms x y
f(x,y) = x^2/(x^2+y^2)
limit(f,y,0)
limit(f,x,0)
```

results in:

```
>> limit(f,y,0)
 
ans(x) =
 
1
 
>> limit(f,x,0)
 
ans(y) =
 
piecewise(y == 0, 1, y ~= 0, 0)
```

As a limit only exists if the value is the same from all directions, this shows it doesn't.

I know, not ideal, hopefully someone can make it work with complex numbers.